# WHMCS: How I can allow a "Management Tools - DNS Management" for all new domains by default?

Tags: dns, whmcs

I need add an ability to manage all registered domains for its owners. I can add it per-user via Clients page, but it not automated. Also I can add this ability via Domain Pricing dialog, but it will cause a 'buying' this feature. How I can do that without any 'buy' dialogs, for all users? I can't see it in options, may be it possible by some code tweaks?

Screenshot: [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution on WHMCS forum.

Easiest way: modify configuredomains.tpl and configureproductdomain.tpl for automatically opening configuredomains.tpl right after domain purchasing, ticking dnsmanagement checkbox and redirecting to viewcart.tpl.